# Linux rename time stamped file

Tags: linux, bash, timestamp, rename

i have some files with timestamp (XXX_20160125-17.dmp) and i want to rename to XXX_20160124.dmp (-1 day, and only YYYYMMDD).
I try a few things but doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What did you try?  Also, check out the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour for more information on asking questions in a way that will attract quality answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ls *.dmp | 
 perl  -lne '
    m/(.*_)(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d).*(\.dmp)/; 
    chomp($d = qx(date -d"$2-$3-$4 - 1 day" +%Y%m%d));
    #rename $_, "$1$d$5"  or  die "rename $_ -> $1$d$5: $!\n";
    print "mv $_ $1$d$5";
  '
```

This generates commands like:

```
 mv XXX_20160101-19.dmp XXX_20151231.dmp
 mv XXX_20160125-17.dmp XXX_20160124.dmp
```

Assuming the filenames have no spaces, you can pipe the result into bash.
Or uncomment the 'rename' stmt in the perl script.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much PBI!!

Comment: please tick checkmark with correct answer